# How to despeckle an image in emgucv?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have been trying to despeckle an image but all the available solutions are in Aforge library.
Is there any solution in emgucv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Despeckle, I understand that you want to remove noise from an image. There is a direct way and an indirect way to do that in Emgucv.

1. Direct Way - Use CvInvoke.FastNlMeansDenoising Method, it takes more time but has very good output.
2. Indirect way - Dilate your image using appropriate kernel, threshold and then erode the image. OR use gaussian blur and then threshold.